# Istio Ingress Serving Blank Page does not rendering content

Tags: kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

Getting blank page instead of content while using istio gateway and VirtualService. The webpage is loading with port forwarding but but not with istio-ingress & Virtual services.

Comment: Blank page with response 200 ok is the default page for the ingress that points at nothing. Can you add more details about the ingress and the resource paths? Please also edit your question by adding yamls of your Service, VirtualService and Gateway.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you happen to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in case of such errors, most of the time issue is with gateway configuration and the best place to debug that is in Kiali->istio-configs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).